# Wget Application development Framework returns nothing

Tags: wget, oracle-adf

I am trying to get the data of an application which is build on Oracle Application Development Framework.

Whenver i try to wget the application it returns nothing..no content only returns below content

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=...">
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried to wget the application by passing header values to wget, but it does not make any difference.

**wget command was as below :**

```
wget --header="Host:example.com" --header="User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0." --header="Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" --header="Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5" --header="Proxy-Connection:keep-alive" --header="Referer:http://example.com/Internet/faces/sbig_home" --header="GET:/Internet/faces/sbig_home?_afrLoop=19302770119376498&_afrWindowMode=0&_afrWindowId=null HTTP/1.1" http://example.com/
```

**Expected result is html content of website application.**

**Below is the output of wget with --debug option(I have changed the url with example.com)**

```
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.13.4 on linux-gnu.

URI encoding = `UTF-8'
--2014-05-14 09:41:18--  http://exaple.com/
Resolving exaple.com (exaple.com)... 202.59.244.48
Caching exaple.com => 202.59.244.48
Connecting to exaple.com (exaple.com)|202.59.244.48|:80... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x08823ed0 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Host: exaple.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://exaple.com/Internet/faces/sbig_home
GET: /Internet/faces/sbig_home?_afrLoop=19302770119376498&_afrWindowMode=0&_afrWindowId=null HTTP/1.1

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 06 May 2014 19:33:42 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 03 Aug 2013 10:45:27 GMT
ETag: "27400a-73-4e308c5f11fc0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20, max=999
Server: Oracle-Application-Server-11g Oracle-Web-Cache-11g/11.1.1.6.0 (G;max-age=0+0;age=0;ecid=99079302593879470,0:1)
Content-Length: 115

---response end---
200 OK
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Length: 115 [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html.2'
```

Comment: What was the exact command you used to nvoke Wget? What was the expected result? And could you also share the output of Wget with the --debug option to allow us to gather as much data about the problem as possible?

Comment: @darnir Thank you for your reply..I have updated the question with details you have asked..have search a lot but not able to find the solution.

Comment: You're not getting nothing, you're getting an HTML page that contains a meta-tag redirect to the actual URL. You can either parse the page, extract that URL, and retrieve it or manually extract the URL and hard-code it in your wget call if you can be sure it won't change (too often).

Comment: @AndrewMedico Tried modifying wget command as wget --header="Host:exaple.com" --header="User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0." --header="Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" --header="Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5" --header="Proxy-Connection:keep-alive" --header="Referer:http://exaple.com/Internet/faces/sbig_home" --header="GET:/Internet/faces/sbig_home?_afrLoop=19302770119376498&_afrWindowMode=0&_afrWindowId=null HTTP/1.1" http://exaple.com/Internet/faces/sbig_home

Comment: getting </script><noscript>This page uses JavaScript and requires a JavaScript enabled browser.Your browser is not JavaScript enabled.</noscript></head$
as the output

Comment: It might just not be suitable for fetching with wget, then.

Comment: As an aside, in your wget command you are setting a header named "GET". This does not make sense / is not appropriate - the HTTP verb is not a header, so the bogus "GET:" header will either be silently ignored by the web server or cause an error.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Want to do that using wget only.I have removed GET thing but still getting the same content. Can you suggest me something else??

Comment: done some parameter changes and now i am able to get the data

Comment: Hi Lussi, Can you please share which parameter changes solved this problem for you?

Comment: Hey @bizz Tried with different parameters,but it didn't helped me that time..then i tried with partial url, and it worked. for example. URL: www.example.com/sometext/sometext/sometext... i tried with www.example.com/sometext/sometext